# Why do I still have None values when I create a list even when using multiple filtering methods?

Tags: python, list, filter, nonetype

I have a piece of code using beautifoulsoup to scrape some specific urls from a web page and have them stored in a list, I try to filter the None values once and for all, I have used the following alternatives:

**1**

```
list_links = [link.get('data-href') for link in BSOBJ.find_all('a') if link is not None]
```

**2**

```
list_links = [link.get('data-href') for link in BSOBJ.find_all('a') if link != None]
```

In both of them I still get the None values, after the list is created I delete them with this line:

```
list_links = list(filter(None, list_links))
```

But I would like to know why I can't filter them with the previous codes and if there is a way to do it directly using list comprehension.

Comment: Even if `link` is not `None`, `link.get('data-href')` can still return `None`... You're basically asking "Why can `x` be `None` when I've already confirmed that `y` isn't `None`?"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem seems to be that `link.get('data-href`) sometimes returns `None`. In order to catch these cases, use

```
list_links = [link.get('data-href') for link in BSOBJ.find_all('a') if link.get('data-href') is not None]
```

and there should be no more `None`s in your list. If `link` itself can be `None`, you should of course keep filtering for this as well.

Answer (score 0):

The trick is to write a generator for "data-href" values and then filter in an outer list comprehension.

```
list_links = [lnk 
    for lnk in (link.get('data-href') for link in BSOBJ.find_all('a'))
    if lnk is not None]
```

Better yet, discard all empty links instead of just `None` in case the page has `data=href=""` attributes.

```
list_links = [lnk 
    for lnk in (link.get('data-href') for link in BSOBJ.find_all('a'))
    if lnk]
```

Answer (score 0):

If you first want to filter links for all `None` and then want to filter `None` generated by `link.get()` function, then this could use nested list comprehension.

```
list_links = [l for l in [link.get('data-href') for link in BSOBJ.find_all('a') if link is not None] if l is not None]
```

or nested if statments.

```
list_links = [link.get('data-href') for link in BSOBJ.find_all('a') if link is not None if link.get('data-href') is not None]
```